# jupyter notebook , python - %reset never ends

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just tried the `%reset` magic command in jupyter notebook.

The cells remains stuck with a [*] indefinitely...

Did anyone have the same problem / know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- First step
  `%reset` is a magic command in IPython, which is used to delete all variables in namespace. `[*]` means that the code block is still running instead of stopping.
  [image: 1-step]
- Second step
  Input `y` as yes in box, then press key `Enter` and then you will delete all variables.
  [image: 2-step]
- Third step
  Because there are no variable `a` and `b`, there will be an error.
  [image: 3-step]

Comment: This is all fine but my problem is that after typing `%reset` the cell never ends computing the command. Hence i never see the second step you depict here.

Comment: @jimbasquiat Can you use `%reset` command in IPython instead of jupyter?